# Extra } or missing \right

Tags: math-mode, equations, line-breaking

I'm having this error each time i try to build the file "Missing \right or extra } error". I tried to figure it out but I could not know in which part is the error. I need break line because without it it will be not aligned and at the margin space. I just start using latex so 
help me please

```
\[
\begin{aligned}   
\Omega = \left\{&(H, H, H), (H, H, T), (H, T, H), (H, T, T), (T, H, H), (T, H, T),\\
                &(T, T, H), (T, T, T)\right\} 
\end{aligned}
\]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6):

an alignment or table cell marked with `&` forms a TeX group, and you need the matching `\left` to be in the same group as the opening `\right`

so

```
\left\{&(
```

is an error as it is like

```
{\left\{} (
```

Just remove the `\left` and `\right` in this instance, or in general replace them by `\bigl` and `\bigr` where the fixed-size versions do not need to be in pairs within the same cell.